# cURL doesn't show JSON data when using Django REST Framework

Tags: json, django, curl, django-rest-framework

I'm having a problem with the tutorial for the [Django REST framework 2](http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/tutorial/1-serialization).  I'm using cURL to test the serializer I've built.  I've also added some snippet data to the database.  According to the tutorial, I should be able to do this:

```
    curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/
```

and see this:

```
    [{"id": 1, "title": "", "code": "foo = \"bar\"\n", "linenos": false, "language": "python", "style": "friendly"}, {"id": 2, "title": "", "code": "print \"hello, world\"\n", "linenos": false, "language": "python", "style": "friendly"}]
```

I would also expect to see an HTTP response code of 200 where the Django server is running.

If I simply enter the URI in my browser, I see the JSON data in my browser and the 200 response code in the Django server console.  But when I run the curl command from the terminal command line, I don't see anything and I get a 301 HTTP response code in the Django console.  What am I doing wrong (or not understanding) that is preventing me from seeing the JSON response in my terminal after I run the curl command?

A second question is, is it possible to query the API from the command line and see the JSON in one's terminal instead of having to view it in the browser?

Here's all the code:

```
    # snippets/models.py 
    class Snippet(models.Model):
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
        code = models.TextField()
        linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                    default='python',
                                    max_length=100)
        style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                                 default='friendly',
                                 max_length=100)

    # snippets/serializers.py
    class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Snippet
            fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')

    # snippets/views.py
    class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
        """An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON."""
        def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
            content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
            kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
            super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

    @csrf_exempt
    def snippet_list(request):
        """
        List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
        """
        if request.method == 'GET':
            snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
            serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    # snippets/urls.py
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^snippets/$', views.snippet_list),
    ]
```

Comment: 301 is a redirect. Where is it trying to redirect to?

Comment: probably your request is not authenticated.

Comment: Note also, DRF is now on version 3.7; why are you using the version 2 tutorial?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Now that I think about it, the view returns a JSONResponse which inherits from HttpResponse so I think that's why the 301.  Does that sound right?  I'm using v2 because I'm running Django 1.8.  and DRF v3 requires Django >= 1.10.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta There's no authentication going on.

Comment: could you share your code ?

Comment: No I'm not sure why you think JSONResponse would be a 301. As I say, this is a redirect; the response will tell you what the destination of the redirect is, which will help debug the issue.

Comment: Could you try `json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', snippets))`?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem. I thought it will appear in the browser but you have to check it in the terminal. According to the documentation I have installed [httpie](https://github.com/httpie/httpie#installation) and it worked perfectly for me. Please try the following command in the terminal hope it will work :)

```
pip install httpie
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/2/
```